# Send Notification Mail to Multiple users suing SMTP each having different Message

Tags: c#, smtp

I have to send notification to a array of users in the to-recipients and each user has a different message body which is stored in another array.
When i try to use multiple calls to SMTP.send() to send the notification to each user (i tried testing for 2 users) one by one with their respective message body, I get Exception like 
"{"A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 10.1.11.16:25"}".

where as it works fine in the case when make a single SMTP.send call where i have ';' separated recipients and same message body.
How do I Solve it.

Controller code sending the array of users and message in array.

```
string[] emailBodyList = FormatedEmail.ToArray(); 
string[] emailIdList = emailIDs.ToArray(); DMS.Common.Encyptor.NotificationSend(FromEmail, ToEmail, CCEmail, BCCEmail, model.MailSubject, emailBodyList, emailIdList);
```

In the Encryptor.cs the SMTP method:

```
public static void NotificationSend(string FromEmail, string ToEmail, string CCEmail, string BCCEmail, string EmailSubject, string[] EmailBody = null, string[] emailID =null)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < EmailBody.Length ; i++)
    {
        string notificationBody = EmailBody[i];
        string notificationTo = emailID[i];
        EmailSend(FromEmail, notificationTo, null, null, EmailSubject, notificationBody);

    }
}

public static void EmailSend(string FromEmail, string ToEmail, string           CCEmail, string BCCEmail, string EmailSubject, string EmailBody= null, string emailID = null)
{
    var email = new MailMessage();

    email.From = new MailAddress(FromEmail);

    string[] toemails = ToEmail.Split(';');
    foreach (string str in toemails)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(str) && str.Contains('@'))
        {
            email.To.Add(new MailAddress(str.TrimEnd(new char[] { ',' })));
        }
    }

    //email.Headers.Add("Reply-To", "saeed.badar@unibetonrm.com");

    // Add CC
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(CCEmail))
    {
        string[] ccemails = CCEmail.Split(';');
        foreach (string str in ccemails)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(str) && str.Contains('@'))
            {
                email.CC.Add(new MailAddress(str.TrimEnd(new char[] { ',' })));
            }
        }
    }
    // Add BCC
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(BCCEmail))
    {
        string[] bccemails = BCCEmail.Split(';');
        foreach (string str in bccemails)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(str) && str.Contains('@'))
            {
                email.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(str.TrimEnd(new char[] { ',' })));
            }
        }
    }

    email.IsBodyHtml = true;
    email.Body = EmailBody;
    email.Subject = EmailSubject;

    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
    smtpClient.Host = AppConfig.GetValue("SmtpHost").ToString();
    smtpClient.Port = int.Parse(AppConfig.GetValue("SmtpPort").ToString());
    //smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
    smtpClient.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
    smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(AppConfig.GetValue("SmtpServerUserName").ToString(), AppConfig.GetValue("SmtpServerPassword").ToString());
    smtpClient.Send(email);
}
```

Comment: sending mail to single user also fails with same exception

Answer (score 0):

The error message seems to be saying that the error has nothing to do with the type of emails you are trying to send.

Does your SMTP need your windows credentials to log you in? You seem to be trying to do both. Since you are specifying a username and password, try setting

```
smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
```

before

```
smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(AppConfig.GetValue("SmtpServerUserName").ToString(), AppConfig.GetValue("SmtpServerPassword").ToString());
```

Also, you need to decide whether you are going to use `CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials` or not.

Make sure your firewall isn't blocking the connection to the SMTP server, and that your credentials are correct.

Comment: Thank you i tried setting smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
but it doesnt seem to work. I am seeing  the same exception. The control comes out of the loop.